# Words in an actual ad

Tags: word-usage

"Quench your thirst" makes sense, while "Refresh your thirst" seems to me to not make sense, but "Refresh your thirst" are the words in an actual Coke ad. Does "Refresh your thirst" make sense?

Comment: The slogan has made you think about Coke a second or two longer than usual - therefore it has worked.

Comment: Non-serious answer: Coke contains so much sugar and similar that it does indeed cause more thirst than it quenches. Hence it actually refreshes your thirst and the slogan is technically correct.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft A non-serious response to your "non-serious answer": Quite so! The next thing we know is that they'll be adding salt to the mix.

Comment: To Peter Point: The Non-serious answer was a great other side of the argument; "Coke contains so much sugar and similar that it does indeed cause more thirst than it quenches. Hence it actually refreshes your thirst and the slogan is technically correct." is maybe the only YES answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Quite so! The Coke ad, *"Refresh your thirst"*, doesn't work at all! Coke's advertising agency has fallen flat this time, just like an open bottle of the stuff that has been lying around for days. *Pepsi* must be jumping for joy at their arch-rival's sloppy slogan! It's not the *Real Thing* any more.

**Refresh:** (verb). Give new strength or energy to; reinvigorate (Oxford Dictionary online)

So, what this Coke ad is asking us to do is to make our thirst worse, not slake it! Well, I suppose, this might be some kind of dastardly subliminal ploy by the people at Coke to get the masses to do them a favor by **running up** a thirst, not quenching it. More thirst, more Coke, more corporate profits.

Coke should take a leaf out of another iconic beverage, *Heineken* lager. They got is right with their decades-long slogan that reminded us that, *Heineken **refreshes** the parts others cannot reach*. (*The Guardian* online edition 5 March 2003).

Comment: It's not possible to say whether the ad works. You'll have to take a look at follow-on sales. This is advertising, where neither the rules of syntax nor the rules of logic define success.

Comment: @deadrat Checkout the NASDAQ on Monday morning. I'll dump my stock in Coke and buy into Pepsi.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/refresh), **refresh** means

> Give new strength or energy to; reinvigorate

Thus, the ad means reinvigorate your thirst, that is, drink the Coke and become thirstier. Not the message they intended.

[The Lexington Herald Leader](http://www.kentucky.com/living/food-drink/article44432607.html) says:

> **Quench your thirst, refresh your palate with cool drink ideas**

This slogan makes a lot more sense!  The recipes are attractive too: fresh fruit, fizzy water, syrups, lots of ice.